# jquery create dynamic form input from sqlite data

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, submit

i am in mobile app. I store in sqlite some student exams like this

classes...........student.......grade......................new grade

class 1...........name 1........previous exams.......

class 1...........name 2........previous exams.......

class 1...........name 3........previous exams.......

and i want to create a form like this

```
<label name1 - previous exams>  <INPUT FIELD NEW GRADE1>
<label name2 - previous exams>  <INPUT FIELD NEW GRADE2>
<label name3 - previous exams>  <INPUT FIELD NEW GRADE3>
 ....

submit button
```

how can i do this???

please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways of doing this. Your best bet is to use JSON to tell your server-side script to create values that you want, then from your jquery code you can create the input list using code similar to this one:

```
$.getJSON('happyserver.php', function(data) {
var items = [];

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
items.push('<label id="' + key + '"><input id="' + val + '">');
 });

$('<div/>', {
'class': 'my-new-list',
 html: items.join('')
 }).appendTo('body');
});
```

You got the lingo! For further info, check jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/